# Moving Asp.Net WebAPI into a Separate Site from Asp.Net MVC site for AngularJS App

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

We have a Asp.Net MVC 5.0 project which uses AngularJS for front end. The project has WebAPI Controller in the same project and it is deployed to same website. The application is built with Individual User Account project template and uses Asp.Net Identity and Claims. There is file upload module where users upload some 100MB+ files that goes through webapi and ng-file-upload plugin. Due to increase in user base we wanted to quickly improve the upload speed by separating API alone into a separate site in a new server and scale it when needed. Since API controller is currently under ASP.Net MVC solution which uses OWIN cookie authentication the API is authorized by the cookie authentication middleware. 
What is the quick way to get the API into a separate site? I beleive we need to implement OAUTH token based on the MVC site and make the new API site to consume the token by enabling CORS. If we do this we are not sure if we need to remove cookie based authentication and re-implement authentication using the new token based authentication. Are there any other approach we can take here by still using cookie based authentication for the Asp.Net MVC site and separating api into a new site?

Note- We also plan to build Mobile app using this API so we believe we have to separate the webapi into a separate site and bring OAuth token based authorization.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Bala

Answer (score 0):

If your mvc site is going to be only client side code only without any major back-end c#. This requires no security as your data comes from API which is what needs to be secured. If you dont want to seperate the two in different domains. Angular will need to read the user information being sent from the server which is why HTTPs only encrypted cookie will not work. If they are going to be different server and domain, plus you need multiple consumers of the API, you should move to oAuth and bearer token based login with refreh tokens and the whole thing. This way you can scale the api into multiple load balancers and still use the bearer token and this would be stateless. That being said you can still achieve this with cookie by storing the token in cookie that way, angular can parse and use the values and the api can validate the signature of the token and use the values. With them having to be on the same domain so they can share the cookie. This can be done without using cookie and simply using LocalStorage as well.

Comment: The MVC site is hybrid it has backend C# code for some modules and uses AngularJS for some modules. Thats why it uses cookie authentication and since the API is under the same site it is accessed after cookie authentication happens. So, if we enable OAuth token authentication in MVC site and separate the API into a new domain in a different server and can it still send the token? If so, how does the token can be obtained after the cookie authentication from MVC site to send it to the new API site? Any pointers?

Comment: Using cookies as they are shared among two domains on the same parent domain. You may not even need to use oAuth for this. You can simply use same machine key in both the api and mvc which will allow the mvc encrypted cookie to be decrypted by api. I personally don't recomend this solution as its headed in the wrong direciton, but it will get the job done. Without even needing oAuth the regular cookie auth will work in both. (They must share machine key and domain)

Comment: So, do you mean if mvc site(parentsite.com) and if the api is api.parentsite.com in a different server and make machine key same it will work? What about session? it is not be available in api server right? how will the same cookie will be authenticated in api server?

Comment: Correct, however session will not work, you will have to use cookie or database to store any extra information. The only content that these two websites share is the cookie. Having same machine key will allow each other to decrypt the cookies and use it's content.

Comment: Sorry, i am still not clear. The cookie will have the session id to identify the user right then how does the another server(which API) will be able to identify the user with the cookie alone?

Comment: Gotcha, okay so your cookie is using session, sorry I missed that part, I assumed it was kvs and signed. There isn't going to be any sharing between the two mvc and api.
1) add custom info in the cookie and have the api parse that and use it without session. You'll be using session in mvc just not in api. 2) move to oAuth bearer and store that in a cookie.This will work same as above except you will store all your info in the cookie ( ensure this is an encrypted token not signed. Do not save signed token in a cookie unless it contains only safe information (as they can be parsed and read from